# Can fill_between range to infinty with custom transform?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to fill the figure with color between one curve and infinity ?

I am looking for something like `ax.fill_between( x, y, 'inf' )`

I don't want to fill up only to y.max() or ax.get_ylim() because I want to be able to zoom out and move around the view with color always filling the upper part of the curve.

Finally, the best I could come with was the following code that does fill to infinity but in both directions +inf/-inf and only works if y>0:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plot.subplots()
x = np.arange(0, 4 * np.pi, 0.01)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.fill_between(x, 0, 1, where = [True]*len(y), transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), color = 'blue', alpha = 0.3 )
ax.fill_between(x, 0, y, color = 'white', alpha = 1)
plot.show()
```

What I really need is to make the following line of code work:

```
ax.fill_between( x, y, 1, where = [True]*len(y), transform=custom_transform )
```

The custom transform has to consider the second argument y in data coordinate and the third argument 1 in axe coordinate.

However, I don't know if this is possible and custom transforms are a bit too much for my skill level.

Comment: What about setting the background colour to something, and then fill_between your lower limit and the curve with something else?

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible example including test data for x and y? Also including the imports and the creation of a simple figure?  You could try `ax.fill_between(x, y, max(y))`. Adding `ax.margins(x=0, y=0)` will avoid strange-looking whitespace.

Comment: JohanC, I added a code example. I really want the fill to go to infinity. I want to plot other curves on the same figure, use the zoom etc..., and still have color up to infinity.

Comment: When doing imports, use standard aliases. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. `.plot` is a method and using it as the alias will be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You can't set the upper limit to infinity, we need an actual number.

One option is you just set the upper limit to something very big, which you are unlikely to ever reach when panning/zooming, e.g. 1e32:

```py
ax.fill_between(x, y, 1e32)
```

Alternatively, you can use a callback on the axes to perform an action whenever the y-limits change; in this case, we will update the [`PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) returned by [`ax.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) whenever the plot area is updated. There are several ways we could do this, but none are particularly straightforward. Here, I use the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71091710/588071), in which we plot a dummy `fill_between` to get the new vertices for the `PolyCollection` with the updated y-limit, then update the original `PolyCollection`, and remove the dummy instance.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0, 4 * np.pi, 0.01)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y)

fill = ax.fill_between(x, y, 2 * y.max())
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2 * y.max())

def on_ylims_change(event_ax):
    
    # Create a dummy PolyCollection with the new y-limit,
    # to use the vertices created, then remove the dummy
    dummy = ax.fill_between(x, y, event_ax.get_ylim()[1], alpha=0)
    dpaths = dummy.get_paths()[0]
    dummy.remove()

    # Update our original PolyCollection with the new vertices
    fill.set_paths([dpaths.vertices])

ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', on_ylims_change)

plt.show()
```

You should be able to zoom/pan/set the limits to anything, and the fill will always reach the top of your axes.

Tested and works with python `v3.10.12` and matplotlib `v3.7.2`, and python `v3.11.5` and matplotlib `v3.8.0`

Comment: `ax.fill_between(x, y, 1e32)` does not work for me because the default zoom is now 1e32 on y axis. Your code snippet does not execute properly on my computer. The fill color is strangely positioned above the sine curve and does not touch it.  The default zoom is also messed up.

Comment: @Altaris, both should be solved by setting the y-limits on the plot, for example adding `ax.set_ylim(-2, 2 * y.max())` after `ax.fill_between`. I've edited the answer

Comment: Thanks @tmdavison. Your solution works. It will probably suit most people out there. However, for my specific application, it's not ideal. I'm building this generic plot tool. The user can plot several curves. I would have to manage the y limits manually now. The callback function can get a bit tricky if this highlight feature is used for several curves on the same plot. Feasible but more complex that what I would have liked. I believe using a transform would be the best option (I edited the question).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ax.get_ylim()` for the limits, and this would change based on the range of the data in the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0, 4 * np.pi, 0.01)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.sin(x)-x
ax.plot(x, y1)
ax.plot(x, y2)

ax.fill_between(x, y1, ax.get_ylim()[1], color='skyblue')
ax.fill_between(x, y1, ax.get_ylim()[0], color='lightgreen')
ax.fill_between(x, y2, ax.get_ylim()[0], color='orange')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anonymous but I don't want to fill up to ax.get_ylim() because I want to be able to zoom out and move around the view with color always filling the upper part of the curve. It's really infinity that I am looking for.